# Use Tkinter in OOP approach

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

right now I know how to create a frame and ask for a directory path and file names using the code I found in stack overflow (Thanks to stack overflow). I need the path and file names (selected by user) somewhere else in my script. Here is the code:

```
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog
class TkFileDialogExample(Tkinter.Frame):

  def __init__(self, root):
    Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, root)

    # define buttons
    Tkinter.Button(self, text='askopenfilename', command=self.askopenfilename).pack()
    Tkinter.Button(self, text='askdirectory', command=self.askdirectory).pack()

  def askopenfilename(self):
    self.file = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()

  def askdirectory(self):
    self.path = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()

if __name__=='__main__':
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    TkFileDialogExample(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
myFileDialog = TkFileDialogExample(root)
print myFileDialog.file
```

But what I do not know, is how to use the path and file names outside of the class?
This way I got this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx .py", line 24, in <module>
    myFileDialog = TkFileDialogExample(root)
  File "C:\Users\xxx.py", line 5, in __init__
    Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, root)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2453, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1974, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
TclError: can't invoke "frame" command:  application has been destroyed
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Save them as attributes, like `self.path=<path>`, and then interrogate your class instance: `myFileDialog = TkFileDialogExample(root); myFileDialog.path`.

Comment: @Pier Paolo Thank you so much. I did what you said and change my code. But I am still getting error. I show the error message in the main question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty way could be to use a `global` variable that is defined in the main body of the script and then it is set during the `mainloop`. In this case I used a dictionary to store in a single variable all the data you need.

```
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog
class TkFileDialogExample(Tkinter.Frame):

  def __init__(self, root):
    Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, root)

    # define buttons
    Tkinter.Button(self, text='askopenfilename',
                   command=self.askopenfilename).pack()
    Tkinter.Button(self, text='askdirectory',
                   command=self.askdirectory).pack()

    self.file = '' # initialize attributes as empty strings
    self.path = '' #

    global outputValues

  def askopenfilename(self):
    self.file = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename() # set attribute
    outputValues['file'] = self.file           # set element of global variable
    print self.file

  def askdirectory(self):
    self.path = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()    # set attribute
    outputValues['path'] = self.path           # set element of global variable
    print self.path

if __name__=='__main__':
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    TkFileDialogExample(root).pack()
    myFileDialog = TkFileDialogExample(root)
    outputValues = {}                          # define global variable
    myPath = myFileDialog.path
    root.mainloop()
    for key, val in outputValues.iteritems():  # the mainloop is over, but
        print key, val                         # the data you set is still
                                               # available
```

The downside is that usually global variables "pollute" the namespace making it hard to track down bugs, so they are often frowned upon. Maybe some other user can provide a better way.

#### First Version

I would suggest that you *initialize* (to empty strings) the attributes `path` and `file` in the `__init__` method and set them to the user input's value when pressing the buttons.

```
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog
class TkFileDialogExample(Tkinter.Frame):

  def __init__(self, root):
    Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, root)

    # define buttons
    Tkinter.Button(self, text='askopenfilename',
                   command=self.askopenfilename).pack()
    Tkinter.Button(self, text='askdirectory',
                   command=self.askdirectory).pack()

    self.file = '' # initialize attributes as empty strings
    self.path = '' #

  def askopenfilename(self):
    self.file = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename() # set attribute
    print self.file

  def askdirectory(self):
    self.path = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()    # set attribute
    print self.path

if __name__=='__main__':
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    TkFileDialogExample(root).pack()         # these lines must be *before*
    myFileDialog = TkFileDialogExample(root) # root.mainloop()
    root.mainloop()
```

About the error you get, the important part is:

```
TclError: can't invoke "frame" command:  application has been destroyed
```

which tells you that once you close the window (that is, you exit the `mainloop` of the `root` object) you cannot reference `root` anymore and so you cannot attach another child (`myFileDialog = TkFileDialogExample(root)`) to it.
Just move those two lines *before* `root.mainloop`, that is, where the object still exists.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. The code works. But what I need is to use the path(self.path), out side the class. when I close the frame.

Answer (score 0):

To use the file name outsidee the class just save it as an attribute then call instace to get it:

```
#Here we are outside the class

if __name__=='__main__':
   root = Tkinter.Tk()
   myFileDialog = TkFileDialogExample(root)
   myFileDialog.pack()
   print myFileDialog.file
   root.mainloop()
```